DateTimeFormatter get local time instead of using hard coded time zone
I have these 2 lines:
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")).withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
String s = dateFormatter.format(Instant.now());

Instead of UTC I would like to get my local time. Is it possible to do it generic, i.e. not replace "UTC" with e.g. "America/New_York"?
I did try
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"));
String s = dateFormatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now());

but I get

ZonedDateTime.now() is not allowed because it silently uses the system default time-zone. You must pass an explicit time-zone (e.g., ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))


Why not dateFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now());?

I can't reproduce your error, can you create minimal, reproducible example?

I don't know either where that warning comes from, but you're lucky to get it as that will likely give you the 'wrong' time, for the reason given in the warning, and you won't get a clue as you've 'formatted away' the timezone

What is the full stacktrace of that error?

well if you must cheat the system that is warning you, you can try ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()) (basically the same values as LocalDateTime.now() but no time zone)

But be aware, that even dateFormatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())) might give you the 'wrong' time. It certainly does for me

And setting the timezone on the formatter solves this problem, as per the answer by @Youcef LAIDANI

You just need `withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).

@g00se Because a ZonedDateTime knows which time zone it belongs to, which prevents a lot of errors, and because we want to pass a time zone to now() for readability and to prevent misunderstanding and more errors. Even if we pass ZoneId.systemDefault().

@Anonymous I'm not sure I understand your sentence beginning Even if we pass...

@g00se I think Anonymous meant that it is generally better to explicitly pass a ZoneId rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone, even if that means passing ( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) rather than (). To which I would concur.

Yes, of course the irony of all this worry about ZonedDateTime is that it's entirely unnecessary as it's the wrong type to be using. The use case is met by LocalDateTime

@g00se You can fight your way through with LocalDateTime and ZoneId if you insist. But why would you want to put the burden on yourself and your colleagues to keep track of date and time being in North American Eastern Time? ZonedDateTime is happy to carry that burden for you. I consider it good practice to let it.

Err... yes but the OP wants a String containing the "local time" and it doesn't contain the timezone in its format

@g00se This was clear all the time. I still mean what I said.
